# Rule will not create drupal user record for CiviCRM contact

Tags: drupal, user-account, rules

Was trying to set up a rule to create drupal user records linked to CiviCRM records that do not have them,
The rule is this:

EVENT
CiviCRM Contact has been created
Contact has been updated

Conditions
 NOT Drupal User Account can be created for user (this condition creates the user)
Parameter: CiviCRM Contact: [civicrm-contact:civi-user..., Activate Account: true, Send account notification email: true, Instant signin: false

Actions
Create or Load Linked Drupal User Account
Parameter: CiviCRM Contact: [civicrm_contact], Activate Account: true, Send account notification email: true
Provides variables: Created or Loaded Drupal User (civicrm_user)

Show a message on the site
Parameter: Message: Drupal User Linked or...

Unfortunately we don't seem to be able to trigger the rule by updating a contact, we just seem to get this error in the watchdog:

MESSAGE Unable to get variable civicrm_contact, it is not defined.

Does anyone know how to get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a blog [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-for-single-or-multiple-contacts-via-civi-imports-and) about creating Drupal users by adding a civicrm tag (as one option for achieving this) and triggering a Drupal Rule from that which you may find it useful.

Comment: The rules in this blog post no longer work with the latest version of CiviCRM Entity unfortunately.

Comment: This post provides a rule that does work with the latest version of CiviCRM entity: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16508/setting-up-rule-to-link-civicrm-contact-with-drupal-7-account

Answer (score 3):

There's a working recipe on [this CiviCRM wiki page](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Creating+a+Drupal+user+for+every+CiviCRM+contact).  There's also an excellent discussion on the old forums [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32677.0).  In particular, I'd make sure you have all the modules named on that second link installed.